# How to see a Page's Pageviews by the referral Source on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

For any given page, I want to know how many pageviews (or unique pageviews) originated from a given Source.

However, if I simply create a table with Primary Dimension = Page, Secondary Dimension = Source, Metric = Pageviews, then I suspect I will only be seeing values for when that Page is the landing page.

How can I see all the pages that users from a given Source visited?

Answer (score 1):

To view the traffic source data for a page. You'll need to use the following steps.

1. Click on "Behavior"
2. Click on "All Pages" under "Site Content" section
3. Click on the Page for which you want to view the data
4. Select the Secondary Dimension as "Source" or "Source / Medium"

This will show you the Traffic Sources for the selected pages as shown in the screenshot below. It will include all the page views including Landing page & Exit pages.

[image: Pageviews by Traffic Source]